# Communication between Hyperledger Fabric Network with Other Blockchain Private Network (e.g. R3 Corda)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, corda, ibm-blockchain

Is it feasible to communicate between two blockchain platforms ? For example Hyperledger Fabric Network with R3 Corda.

If yes then which protocol should be used and how it works?

Ideally can we update ledger of other blockchain platform from Hyperledger Fabric Network? How consensus will work on this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about Corda, but as far as I know, there is no possibility to get them to communicate on a *blockchain-layer* since this would require sth in the direction of MultiSignature transactions.

**My actual answer:**
It seems you will have to do it the **old-fashioned** way and build APIs on both sides and then make sure communication is secure and valid.

You could do sth. like syncing them on a database-layer level, but this will be ugly as f*** and I would highly recommend against it, since you could easly compromise security AND integrity of you whole system.

Sorry I'm mostly providing #FUD, but the corporate blockchains are far behind the development of the Open Cryptocurrency- and Smart Contract Community.

Answer (score 0):

if you should mean *transactions* for communication, then check out the **Hyperledger Quilt** Tool (wiki see [here](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/quilt/Hyperledger+Quilt)). It is the Hyperledger implementation of the [Interledger Protocol](https://interledger.org/rfcs/0027-interledger-protocol-4/) and allows making transactions across ledgers (distributed ledgers and non-distributed ledgers). This issue is generally known as *Atomic Swaps*.

Interoperability was also researched by consultancy agencies like accenture and deloitte, see [here](https://www.ledgerinsights.com/accentures-enterprise-blockchain-interoperability/).

Best regards,
Timo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at [Hyperledger Cactus](https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2020/05/13/tsc-approves-hyperledger-cactus-as-new-project)

Hyperledger Cactus is a blockchain integration tool designed to allow users to securely integrate different blockchains. This pluggable architecture helps enable the execution of ledger operations across multiple blockchain ledgers, including Hyperledger Besu, Hyperledger Fabric, Corda, and Quorum available today, with the aim of developers continually adding support for new blockchains in the future.